# Svelte: Remount component to overwrite media elements

Tags: video, html5-video, svelte, svelte-component, svelte-3

- Context

In my Svelte app, I have multiple pages, each showing one or multiple videos.
For rendering the videos I reuse a **video component** (simplified):

```js
// video component
<video poster="{source.thumb}">
    <source type="{source.mime}" src="{source.source}" >
</video>
```

The **main page** receives the video content via an api and calls the video component:

```
// calling video component on main page
<script>
    let source = {
        thumb: 'thumb.jpg',
        source: 'video.mp4',
        mime: 'video/mp4',
    };
</script>
<Video source={source} />
```

**All works fine**, the video is rendered and can be played.

- Problem

**But:** when I navigate or want to replace a video with another, the old video element somehow still exists and playback continues.

I could use `beforeUpdate()` to pause the video. But then, the new video weirdly is loaded at the exact same playback time and everything gets mixed up. Or if I remove the video element in `beforeUpdate()`, it doesn't get filled with the new information.

It kinda makes sense, because the `video` media element stays the exact same thing while only attributes and content change. Thus the state and already buffered source remains.

**I somehow would need to assure, that when the data changes, the video component must completely be remounted.**
Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: it's counterintuitive to me that the old playback would still be in effect when the *source* changes. The snippet shown here is not reactive, how does the new source loading happens?

Comment: Every on-site link triggers a function that loads data from an API to render a new page, also including videos. I just replace the data object and all content updates as expected. Unless videos, the stay the same as long as the new page also features a video.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Generally, svelte does not arbitrarily duplicate elements, hence my question. The script shown here does not replace the data however, and that data replacement is probably important in solving the problem. Can you add the code to your question? Otherwise, maybe use the inspector to see what actually happens in the elements. If the video elements are duplicated, it would be a clue as to what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some trial and error and with the help of @voscausa it now works:

```js
<script>
    export let source;

    let renderVideo = true;

    $: { reMountVideo( source.source ) }
    function reMountVideo(){
        renderVideo = false;
        setTimeout(() => renderVideo = true, 0);
    }
</script>
{#if renderVideo === true}
    <video poster="{source.thumb}">
        <source type="{source.mime}" src="{source.source}" >
    </video>
{/if}
```

It checks if the video url changes, and if so, triggers `reMountVideo()`.

Answer (score 7):

To trigger a rerender of the video when the source changes, a [{#key}](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-key) block could be used [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c3cb244841124ee2a5e74f0e704e534d?version=3.47.0)

```
<script>
    export let source;
</script>

{#key source}
<video poster="{source.thumb}" controls>
    <source type="{source.mime}" src="{source.source}" >
</video>
{/key}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same kind of problem with the `<input type="file" ....>`
And solved it using:

```
let video = true:
function reMountVideo() {
  video = false; 
  setTimeout(() => video = true, 0);
} 

{#if video }
  <Video source={source} />
{/if}
```

I did not try [$destroy](https://svelte.dev/docs#$destroy)

Comment: why use the setTimeout instead of reassigning true directly?

Comment: To queue the true after the render.

Comment: Where do I call `reMountVideo()`? If I call it from a `beforeUpdate()` or `afterUpdate()`, it creates an infinite loop.

Comment: You call it only when you replace one video for another or after you have finished a video. So not all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Current version of svelte supports this. This attaches a callback that is called on `video` every time the property `src` changes.

```js
<script>
    let src = ...
    function load(node, src){
        if(src){
            node.src = src;
            node.load();
        } 
        return {
            update(src){
                if(src){
                    node.src = src;
                    node.load();
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<video use:load={src}>
```